# Can you safely use the telephone during a lightning storm?

Tags: telephone, lightning

Everyone's heard the lecture on how you shouldn't use the telephone in a storm unless it's an emergency, due to a risk of electrical shock. My understanding is this is true and numerous people have died from lightning striking the telephone wires and electrocuting telephone users. Most reports say lightning enters through one's ear.

How exactly would this work? Most telephone receivers are plastic and plastic does not conduct electricity as well as metal or water. The copper wire from the PSTN connects to the telephone, but the only part of the telephone that you would touch is made out of plastic.

So how exactly can using the telephone be dangerous? Can lightning travel into the plastic part of a receiver and through the air into someone's ear? Is there a way to be safe when using a landline telephone or prevent this from happening?

**For example, if you have a speakerphone connected to the line, does that reduce the risk? If you hold the receiver away from your ear, are you safe? If you put metal or water near the telephone, will the lightning strike that instead of your ear?**

*If you haven't figured it out, I'm talking about normal landline telephones, not the crazy alternatives that people try using nowadays.

Comment: Thought about how lightning travels *into* the phone line? Any reason to believe it can't use the same means to travel out of it again?

Comment: ["Breakdown voltage 30 kV/cm at 1 atm."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_gas)

Comment: "Can lightning travel into the plastic part of a receiver and through the air into someone's ear?" - Yes, it can. A few mm of air and/or plastic are basically no issue for lightning which, to begin with, has enough voltage to travel hundreds of meters through the air from a cloud to the ground...

Comment: I revised my question to make it less vague - are there any steps you can take to make using the telephone safer? For example, using a speakerphone? Holding receiver away from ear? Putting metal/water near the telephone?

Comment: If you hold the receiver away from your ear, you are still holding the receiver... so the electricity flows through your arm instead of your ear.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Right, but if lightning travels into your ear through the air, it would no longer be able to travel into your ear, is that right? What if you have the receiver hanging on the wall?

Comment: @InterLinked That makes a lot of "what if"... But if you're far away from the phone, it is indeed less likely you get a shock. Hence the recommendation.

Comment: Use a cordless telephone.

Comment: @HandyHowie This question regards corded telephone solutions. Wireless/cordless is not an option

Comment: Standing under a tree is dangerous in a storm, so is walking on a golf course, holding an umbrella, and a host of other things. At least you can *choose* not to make phone calls when there's risk, and that's the best way of minimising that particular risk. Theorising about how you can make a call and still stay safe is pointless, IMHO. Unless you're hoping for a Darwin Award of course.

Comment: *"...plastic does not conduct electricity..."* No, *everything* conducts electricity. Some things just do it better than others. See [Does perfect insulation exist](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150836/does-perfect-insulation-exist).

Comment: How do you pick up a call on a speaker phone without going near it?  Asking how to use a phone safely during a lightning storm is like asking how to make the game of Russian roulette safer. The very question borders on the absurd. Study some photos and accounts of lightning strikes and then get back to us if you still think there is a "safe" way to use any kind of electrical equipment during a lightning storm.

Comment: Nothing is truly safe during a thunderstorm, other than sitting in a steel box with 2" thick walls. It is possible to get struck by lightning both directly and indirectly when you are on the phone. There is no way of determining what your line will do without knowing the location of the strike before hand and its potential. (I know someone who got struck indirectly) Is getting hit while talking on the phone likely? No. Is it risky, Not very. If your risk adverse then don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning travels thousands of feet from the clouds down to the planet. It is also VERY HIGH voltage and VERY HIGH current. Do you really think jumping a few mm from the wiring in the handset to your body is any particular kind of barrier?  Have you ever SEEN the results of a lightning strike?

Comment: Lightning will also vaporize the thin telephone wires. I guess what most people mean when they talk about lightning striking electronic equipment is about the secondary effects of a nearby lightning strike. My neighbor's house was directly hit by lightning: the cable ducts in the walls _exploded_. A hundred yards from there, my whole intercom system was gently fried.

Comment: Lightning doesn't need the thin telephone wires. It vaporizes them because the massive and destructive current has already found a convenient path and the thin telephone wires are just a casualty along the way.  You can throw most of the conventional electrical current flow theory out the window when it comes to lightning.  It is in a whole class by itself.

Comment: Exactly, my point is that the OP's doubts should be answered according to _secondary_ lightning effects. If your house is directly hit by a lightning, holding the phone will be the least of your problems, if you are less than a yard (ten?) from the current path. But if the lightning hits your neighbor's house, what are the chances the inducted voltages will damage a person holding a phone?